# How does the u-boot code written in c get executed?

Tags: embedded-linux, u-boot

I am new to u-boot environment and its logic . I see a lot of code related to power checking and source selection inside u-boot and I see that entire code is written in C. I am wondering if the kernel and rfs location is chosen by the u-boot code (nand flash or sd card) how does the u-boot code get executed itself?

Comment: U-Boot is typically executed as a second- (or even third-) stage boot program.  A ROM boot program is typically the first-stage boot program executed on a processor reset (esp ARM).  Note that U-Boot source code also includes an optional SPL program to load the U-Boot program.  The exact boot sequence is typically dictated by the SoC and boot medium.

Comment: The kernel and file system location, as well as the type of hardware, is conditionally compiled into U-Boot with configuration flags.